# Teste de integração API mysql e nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, testes

Tenho uma API escrita em NodeJS (express) que usa a biblioteca [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) para puxar dados de um banco hospedado na AWS.

Os endpoints da API são basicamente consultas SQL, quase sem lógica associada ao retorno dos dados.

Gostaria de fazer testes nessa API para saber se ele se comporta bem com campos null, inválidos, etc. mas não quero usar o banco de dados em produção para isso.

Devo criar um novo banco de dados idêntico ao original, coloca-lo em nuvem e usa-lo de teste ou exite alguma sugestão melhor?

Comment: pra teste unitário não precisa de banco de dados, faça um mock do banco, senão não vai ser um teste unitário

Comment: Explica melhor por favor @RicardoPontual como seria feito isso? Que biblioteca? Lembrando que não tem quase nenhuma logica, a ideia seria testar se a query está se comportando do jeito esperado para diferentes entradas no banco

Comment: se quer testar a query no banco não é um teste unitário. Teste unitário teste um única classe, um  método

Comment: Certo, mudarei para teste de integração, é mais adequado para a pergunta?